# post an image of input file using javascript to php file

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

is any way to post the image object to php file using javascript that can be alternative for the regular way of uploading image using (enctype="multipart/form-data") ?

I had successfully post values of input text boxes using ajax, any way to post input file fields ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several techniques for this.

One is to utilize an iFrame for the upload.
Check this out: http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Using Iframe for this is one of the best method and keep track of the reponse in Iframe for image uploaded and as soon as you get desired response. Show the image uploaded message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ajax style upload checkout: http://www.plupload.com/ or http://valums.com/ajax-upload/